# Show/Hide all tr-s inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, drupal-7

Here is the html structure

```
<table class="views-table cols-3">
      <caption>
         <h2>LINK(which will hide/show all trs in this table)</h2>
      </caption>
   <thead>
   <tbody>
   ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This table is repeated **n** times with the *same class*. Please help with a js or jquery script that hide/shows all **tr**-s or the whole `<tbody>` in the table where the link was clicked.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('.views-table h2').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but seems my cms doesn't allow me to use jq script. Would you write an js equivalent  function please. I pasted this code in: Views > Header > Global: Text area but for some reason it doesn't load jq. But it loads js (i tested it with alert()).

Comment: I don't know what 'cms' is, where 'Views>Header>Global: Text area' is, and rarely manipulate the DOM without jQuery, so your probably going to need to find someone else (or figure out why jq isn't loading)...

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".views-table h2").click(function(){
       var table = $(this).parents("table");
       var tbody = table.children("tbody");
       if(tbody.is(':visible')){
               tbody.hide();
       }else{
           tbody.show();
       }

});
```

Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/wFcpP/8/

Comment: I'm really sorry, please look my comment at shaun5

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
(jQuery.noConflict())(function($){
    $('.views-table cols-3 h2').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent('.views-table').find('TBODY > TR')[0].is(':visible')) {
            $(this).parent('.views-table').find('TBODY > TR').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).parent('.views-table').find('TBODY > TR').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't consider that the table is repeated n-times with the same class.